# Long value as NaN

Tags: java

I have a case where I need to pass only not null values and not empty Strings to repository.

For Strings, I have kept constant "NULL_VALUE", For Double and Float, I am using NaN.

Similarly is there a way to keep some value for `Long, Integer and Boolean`

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    Float fVal = Float.NaN;
    System.out.println("Float NaN :" + fVal);

    Double dVal = Double.NaN;
    System.out.println("Double NaN :" + dVal);

//  Integer iVal = Integer.NaN;
//  System.out.println("Integer NaN :" + iVal);

//  Boolean boolVal = Boolean.NaB; // Not a boolean

}
```

I am afraid to keep 0 or some large vale (999999999 for int).

What is the best way?

Comment: No, the only non-null `Boolean` values are true and false. That's all that's available. If you want to represent a "not a real value" value, that's traditionally what `null` *is* for. So you'll either need to change the rest of the system to accept null values, or have more information somewhere else expressing whether to treat the column as "not a value".

Comment: "not null value", like 99.99% of the time not ?^^

Comment: You could work with Java8 `Optional` but that might not be what you want

Comment: There are e.g. `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `Long.MAX_VALUE`, but for `Boolean`, I'm afraid you don't have much choices.

Comment: related, but for Scala http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/7018

Comment: for `Boolean` (not `boolean`) you can use 'null'

Comment: @dehasi *I need to pass only not null values*

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, you want to get some suggestions for default values to replace those variables with whenever you encounter a null or an empty `String`? That seems very implementation-specific and not really something we can advise on here... Apart from saying that such a thing doesn't exist for `Boolean` as stated by others.

Comment: If you encounter a null value, log, and don't pass it at all.

Comment: Use 81738741. Chances are slim that value is ever going to be used. /s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understood your question correctly you don't want to persists `null` values to your database.

As the default for objects like `Float`, `Boolean` and so on is `null` you'd have to fallback to the default values of the corresponding primitives eg: `0.0f` for `float`, `false` for `boolean` and so on...

A different approach would be to define your own default values. Like you already said `"NULL_VALUE"` for `String` might not be a that bad, as there is no other alternative.